# "Could not get any response" from WCF service using secure bindings, timeout settings ignored?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, timeout, wcf-binding

I have a service on a remote machine using secure bindings. All of my service configurations are in config files (and I have checked to make sure the right config files are being adjusted.) I have tried to tell the service to timeout at 3 minutes, but every time I make a request that takes longer than a minute, Postman gives me the generic "Could not get any response" page. (It doesn't even give me an error or a stack trace.) This happens exactly at 1 minute. Yes, I even used the stopwatch on my phone to verify it's exactly a minute.

In a different environment that uses non-secure bindings, I know this particular call takes about 90 seconds. I just need this secure environment to wait a little longer!

I'm sorry if my jargon isn't on key, I'm slightly new at this.

My services config file for the WCF service in question looks like this:

```
  <service name="XXX.SolrIndexService.Host.Services.EventIndexService">
        <endpoint address="ajax"
            behaviorConfiguration="ServerReadCookie"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding"
            contract="XXX.SolrIndexService.DataContracts.IEventIndexService" />
  </service>
```

The actual binding configuration is here:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingUnsecure" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpsBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"
                closeTimeout="00:03:00"
                openTimeout="00:03:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:03:00">

      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

These are snippets from the entire configs file, I can post the whole thing if anyone thinks that would be helpful. I also used XXX in place of the client's name just because I'm not sure what the etiquette is with that sort of thing.

I've seen lots of posts regarding WCF timeouts and my general impression is that they're mysterious and picky. I've also checked IIS limits for the site that hosts the service, and it has a general Connection Timeout setting of 120 seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in my particular case I was hitting my service through a load balancer. I did not attempt to change any settings on the load balancer. Instead I decided to hit the service using the specific machine that it was hosted on. After doing that, my timeout settings were obeyed and I'm no longer timing out before the call can be completed.

I'm not sure if that will help anyone in the future, it's rather specific, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using postman you should use the [WCF Client tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx)

this might give you more feedback

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After some attempts, apparently...

"web endpoints (unlike SOAP ones) do not expose metadata, so the test client doesn't know about it when it downloads the WSDL for the service. Unlike SOAP, which has well-defined formats for exposing metadata (WSDL, MEX), web (a.k.a. REST) endpoints do not."

So I'm not having any luck with this one.